# Concatenate multiple text files in macOS

Tags: macos, text-files

I would like to concatenate multiple text files with various extensions (.log, .log.1, .log.2, etc.) into a single file called -concatenated..

I have created this Automator service workflow which doesn't work:

[failed Automator Service Workflow attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOFoW.png)

1. It only text text from the first items in my test (first item is a .log file, while the next one is a .1)
2. I can't figure out how to put the name and extension of the first file selected into a variable.

I am on macOS Big Sur 11.1, in case it is relevant.

It does not have to be automator but I would like something I can do quickly from within finder, either using the contextual menu or using a couple of key strokes (using Alfred for example).